# Can't acces or find BOOTCAMP drive in mac El Capitan

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a late 2012 iMac running El Capitan and here is how the drive shows in Disk Utility and NTFS Paragon. It also doesn't appear in the Finder sidebar even after i checked all the things in the Finder preferences. The funny thing is that if i log into Windows 10 I can easily acces everything from the mac drive. What can i do to make the BOOTCAMP drive appear and be accesible?[image]

Comment: It seems that Paragon is ignoring the drive. Also, there is a mount button when you are clicking on it. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah i tried that, mount and also verify does not seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had this issue too...

It turns out, the disk was in hibernation mode, and Paragon may have been responsible.  In the *System Preferences* pane, go to *Paragon NTFS*, *Volumes Tab*, and check the box (Bottom left) that reads : "Disable Paragon NTFS for Mac".  This is what worked for me.

Also, on startup you may get a Paragon notification that says the disk is in hibernation.  Click on that notification before it disappears and another dialogue box will come up that lets you force a mounting of the disk.  This warns you that you will loose temp info from hibernation mode (which is not a big deal).  This is another way to potentially fix it.

Comment: Oh and restart :)